# Angular directives cannot be use in custom HTML tag

Tags: angular, typescript, devexpress, angular-directive

Here I have the directive decorator that I make to use google map autocomplete API and import it into my HTML component but it does not work when I use custom HTML tags such as `<dx-text-area>` by devexpress but it only work with normal HTML tag.

**This is my directive decorator**

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[google-place]'
})
export class GooglePlacesDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  private element: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.element = elRef.nativeElement;
  }

  getFormattedAddress(place) {
    let location_obj = {};
    for (let i in place.address_components) {
      let item = place.address_components[i];

      location_obj['formatted_address'] = place.formatted_address;
      if(item['types'].indexOf("locality") > -1) {
        location_obj['locality'] = item['long_name']
      } else if (item['types'].indexOf("administrative_area_level_1") > -1) {
        location_obj['admin_area_l1'] = item['short_name']
      } else if (item['types'].indexOf("street_number") > -1) {
        location_obj['street_number'] = item['short_name']
      } else if (item['types'].indexOf("route") > -1) {
        location_obj['route'] = item['long_name']
      } else if (item['types'].indexOf("country") > -1) {
        location_obj['Negara'] = item['long_name']
      } else if (item['types'].indexOf("postal_code") > -1) {
        location_obj['postal_code'] = item['short_name']
      }

    }
    return location_obj;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.element);
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
      this.onSelect.emit(this.getFormattedAddress(autocomplete.getPlace()));
    });
  }
}
```

**This is my component**

```
  setAddress(addrObj) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.addr = addrObj;
      this.addrKeys = Object.keys(addrObj);
    });
  }
```

**And this is my HTML component**

```
  <input 
    type="text"
    class="google-place-input"
    google-place
    (onSelect)="setAddress($event)"
    placeholder="Type to search.."> <!-- It is working for this -->

  <dx-text-area
    type="text"
    class="google-place-input"
    google-place
    (onSelect)="setAddress($event)"
    placeholder="Type to search.."> <!-- But not working on this -->
```

Anyone know why does this happen?

Comment: does the dx-text-area have an onSelect EventEmitter? maybe try change or onChange...

Comment: try using dx-text-box

Comment: @Guntram the dx-text-area does not have onSelevt EventEmitter but have onChange. But i already tried it and still not working only on dx-text-area

Comment: dx-text-box is not helping @Saksham